# How is it possible that I see Facebook URLs in my server logs?

Tags: facebook, apache

I have been seeing URLs in my apache server logs that are clearly meant for another site.  The most common one that I see is Facebook, but I've also seen Tumblr and YouTube.  I am trying to figure out how that could happen.  Here is an example of a request that was logged on my server (I removed the remote IP address):

```
[IP Redacted] - - [21/Sep/2011:13:31:35 +0000] "POST /ajax/chat/buddy_list.php?__a=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 797 "http://www.facebook.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_1) AppleWebKit/534.48.3 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
```

This looks like someone was on facebook.com, using Facebook chat, and for whatever reason the post got sent to my server.  Does anyone have an idea for how this could happen, or how I could go about investigating it further?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when posting a link on Facebook to your site, Facebook will commonly try to get some information (page title, article title, some text, maybe a photo) from the link. I suspect that that's what's happening here.

Comment: I don't think thats it. Why would facebook make POST request to non-existing url with referrer of facebook.com? This doesn't look like server-side request.

Comment: Agreed, these seem like client-side requests.

Answer (score 0):

There are all kinds of script kiddies that try to use your apache server as a proxy. I don't know of any vulnerabilities on this, but results related to that i found also on my logs. You should not worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be "automated 'hacking' scripts blindly trying everything and anything in their arsenal" - similar to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7082/information-on-the-phpmyadmin-probe). If your server handles the requests correctly (i.e. returns an appropriate error page, and doesn't forward them), you should be in the clear.

Comment: I'd like to believe that (although it is disturbing in its own way) but I'm looking for a way to confirm that this is not some kind of mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Check your hosts file if any traffic is being directed or this could be the referer of the website they last used to reach your server.

Also they could be using your server as a proxy to gain access to blocked websites seeing as the traffic is going through you. I'm looking at again and it seems you are blocking Facebook because the 404?

EDIT: You could try blocking common websites from your server using the hosts file to make them piss off.

Comment: What do you mean, check my hosts file for traffic being directed?  The file in /etc/hosts?  I'm not blocking any traffic.  I am responding with a 404 because the requested URL does not exist on my site